# Sums and products involving Fibonacci

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, fibonacci-numbers

In summary, if $\phi$ is the golden ratio, I want to show:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{F_n} &= 4-\phi \\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{F_nF_{n+1}} &= \phi-1 \\
\prod_{n=2}^\infty \bigg( 1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{F_n^2} \bigg) &= \phi.
\end{align}

Comment: Why is it ([tag:contest-math]) and what have you tried?

Comment: The first is easily shown to be false by summing the first few reciprocals. _Perhaps_ $4 - \frac1\phi$ would be the sum.

Comment: its in a book for putnam, yh I checked on wiki and the value was around 3. something, I have tried considering partial sums but to no success, I want to consider some sort of induction possibly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first equation is obviously wrong, since

$$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{2} > 4 - \phi = 4 - \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 2.381966.$$

The other two equations can be easily derived by considering

$$F_n^2 - F_{n-1}F_{n+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks! Yes it is equal to (-1)^n+1, ive done the last two but in regards to the first summation, 4−1/ϕ? as you suggested, any hints?

Comment: I don't think the sum is actually $4 - \frac1\phi$, and I don't know whether the sum of the reciprocals of the Fibonacci numbers is known at all. Double-check your source, if you have made no error transcribing, your source contains a mistake. I don't see an easy way to change it so it's right.

Comment: well the book says 4−ϕ which is incorrect and the ive checked the suggested answer  4−1/ϕ which wikepedia disagrees with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_Fibonacci_constant from 2dp onwards, it says no closed form is known as well.

Comment: Well, [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalFibonacciConstant.html) has closed forms for the reciprocals of even-indexed and of odd-indexed Fibonacci numbers, so "Together, these give the reciprocal Fibonacci constant as" a closed form, but a not particularly convenient one. $4 - \frac1\phi$ was a first guess, since that's roughly in the right ballpark. Considering that the other two are rather easy, I think the book botched the terms of the sum for the first. I have no idea what could have been intended, though.

Comment: yh I saw the proof for the even-indexed one, involving Lambert series and straight away I moved away as I have never come across it before and there aren't any good beginner notes online on it. The book is Problem-Solving Strategies, Arthur Engel